# WooCommerce - change order status with php code

Tags: php, class, object, field, woocommerce

I am trying to change order status in WooCommerce, but I encountered no luck so far. $order instance is created successfully (I know it because `echo $order->status;` works fine, $order_id is also correct. `$order->status = 'pending';` simply doesn't change anything, I do not know why.

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->status = 'pending';
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('pending', 'order_note'); // order note is optional, if you want to  add a note to order
```

Comment: I will check this code out tomorrow and mark this answer as correct if it works :).

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_order() on a non-object in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php on line 54

Comment: @itskawsar this means the order can"t be found, probably wrong $order_id

Answer (score 9):

Working with `woocommerce v4.4`, other answers were not working for me. I had to do it this way,

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$order->set_status('pending');
$order->save();
```

**Note:** Woocommerce internally adds `wc` prefix, you will see it if you view in the database. We do not need to explicitly add it.

Comment: What is the file that it modifies?

Comment: @Dario the code here, saves the status of the order in the database. It doesn't modify a file.

Answer (score 6):

Since Woocommerce version 3.0+ to update status you need to do this

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

if($order){
   $order->update_status( 'pending', '', true );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce change order status

```
$order_id = 10;
$orderDetail = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$orderDetail->update_status("wc-completed", 'Completed', TRUE);
```

The following are the list of available status

```
wc-pending   For Pending payment
wc-processing   For Processing
wc-on-hold   For On hold
wc-completed   For Completed
wc-cancelled   For Cancelled
wc-refunded   For Refunded
wc-failed   For Failed
```