# woocommerce booking status changes woocommerce order status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce bookings.
I'm trying to trigger woocommerce order status to refund if the `woocommerce_booking` status is cancelled. I tried this code but it's not working.

```
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
if ( 'cancelled' == $order->status ) {
   $order->update_status('refund', 'order_note');
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Did yoy check $order->status?

Comment: yes I checked order status. It remains the same. It should change to refund but it's not working.

Comment: spreek jij toevallig Nederlands Jeroen? Ik zit al weken met hetzelfde probleem.
Komt het omdat de order wordt geplaatst via een booking? (woocommerce bookings)

Comment: Yes, i am living in the Netherlands. I am not a real expert but looked on Google and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935358/woocommerce-change-order-status-with-php-code) SO question and [this](https://stanhub.com/how-to-change-order-status-in-woocommerce/) article suggesting your code should work. You could test this by changing to an other status. The [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-refunds/) indicate that refund is only working if your "payment gateway supports it".  Try manually first and update your question with the found results.

Comment: seems nobody understands my question. I need woocommerce booking status (cancelled) to changes woocommerce order status to refund.

Comment: If anyone's still struggling with this, here's a helpful guide: https://wpza.net/woocommerce/change-order-status-to-complete-for-woocommerce-bookings/

Comment: I think you should check this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-refunds/#section-1.   Then take apart what woocommerce is doing behind these actions and just call that PHP yourself.

Answer (score 6):

To update order status on cancel status

```
add_action('woocommerce_cancelled_order','change_status_to_refund', 10, 1);
 function change_status_to_refund($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status('refund', 'order_note');
    exit;
 }
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'wc_order_status_changed', 99, 3 );

function wc_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){
    if( $new_status == "cancelled" ||  $new_status == "refunded" ) {
        //code here.
    }
}
```

If you want use in some class action must be like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', array($this, 'wc_order_status_changed'), 99, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the status of your order and then check your required condition and update it accordingly.

```
$order_status = $order->get_status();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but i have just make it on my latest wordpress/woocommerce install

```
add_action('woocommerce_booking_cancelled', 'my_booking_cancelled_handler', 10, 1);
function my_booking_cancelled_handler ( $booking_id ) {
  $booking = new WC_Booking( $booking_id );
  $order_id = $booking->get_order_id();
  // check order for your business logic
  // refund or not ;-) it's up to you
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this


add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'auto_destroy_failed_orders', 10, 4 );

function auto_destroy_failed_orders( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order )
 {
    if ( ( $new_status == 'completed' )) {
        // Order status complete 
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );

    }else if ( ( $new_status == 'failed' )) {
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );

    }else if ( ( $new_status == 'b2c-shipment' )) {
        // custome status
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );

    }else if ( ( $new_status == 'on-hold' )) {
        // Order status to on-hold
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );

    }else if ( ( $new_status == 'refunded' )) {
        // Order status to refunded
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );

    }else if ( ( $new_status == 'failed' )) {
        // Order status to failed
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );

    }else if ( ( $new_status == 'processing' ) ) {
        // Order status to processing
        $order->update_status( 'custom-status' );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can try this hook!!

```
https://therichpost.com/change-product-order-status-woocommerce-hook
```

Hope this will help you