# Woocommerce order status not updating

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have an API that updates woocommerce order status after a callback from a custom Payment gateway.

```
$order->update_status($status, __("Order #{$order->get_id()} updated via API. Status: {$status}", 'woocommerce'));
```

**`$status`** is returning **`'completed'`**

The strange thing is that the order note gets updated in woocommerce (**`Order status changed from Pending payment to Completed.`**) but the status itself does not update.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935358/woocommerce-change-order-status-with-php-code